# Interpolate TO a grid FROM random points

Tags: c#, interpolation, terrain, delaunay, kriging

I have a series of coordinates that represent data in a 2D scalar field:  x[i], y[i], F[i].  However, x[i] and y[i] are not on a rectilinear grid, they are "randomly" placed. I want to interpolate f[i] so I can estimate its value on a rectilinear grid of locations in x, y.

This problem should be the same height interpolation of a terrain (see http://www.cs.uu.nl/geobook/interpolation.pdf).  For example, if one has a height map of a terrain, it is not necessarily measured on a rectilinear grid.  However, many maps would prefer the height on a rectilinear grid.  Therefore the data must be interpolated to a rectilinear grid.

I use Matlab and it has a **griddata** command that performs interpolation to a rectilinear grid.  The methodology uses Delaunay triangulation and some interpolation that is not described.  I could guess at how this works, but it seems to me that this type of code should've already been written by someone else.

See:  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html?refresh=true for reference regarding how the griddata produces a rectilinear interpolation from "scatter" data.

I want to integrate the code into a C# application, so I'm looking for a library or source code to incorporate.  ALGLIB will perform a cubic spline interpolation from uniformly spaced to uniformly spaced.  I can't find anything that will work with non-uniformly spaced data.

Answer (score 0):

You can make 2 triangles a quadrilateral. IMO a marching cube algorithm gives a rectilinear grid. You can try Paul Bourke conrec algorithm.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your recommendation.  Marching cubes creates a mesh from uniformly distributed data.  CONREC (http://paulbourke.net/papers/conrec/) also seems to require a rectilinear grid.  Right?

Comment: No. Marching cube creates rectilinear grid Delaunay triangulation creates smaller, better grid. DT is also more difficult.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand.  Here are two places I started when researching Marching Cubes:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes and http://graphics.stanford.edu/~mdfisher/MarchingCubes.html .  Each of these describes a method of creating polygonal meshes from a rectilinear "marching" through a known function / surface.  I don't see how that relates to my problem.  Can you point me towards some references or provide some additional details?

Comment: I have a set of data points that are not uniformly distributed.  They sample a plane and the values of a scalar function on that plane.  I wish to re-sample (interpolate) that scalar function to a rectilinear grid.

Comment: Rectilinear is the input. Check the marching cube thing. Paul Bourke also has DT algorithm.

Comment: Take a look at this:  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html?refresh=true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99717/discussion-between-user3533030-and-phpdevpad).

Comment: Are you proposing the nearest neighbor value based upon Manhattan distance to the nearest triangle created by the Delaunay method?

Comment: No. I use linear interpolation.

Comment: I get the impression that Matlab uses DL to create triangles and then linearly interpolates data with the plane formed by the triangles.  I cannot find C# code that performs this interpolation.  Seems like I need to write my own... right?

Comment: You can try my PHP implementation https://contourplot.codeplex.com/ and/or https://cntm.codeplex.com. I created it for NASA.